# how are convexity defects used with SVM classifier opencv c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, classification, svm

I want to use convexity defects of a human hand as input to a classifier. I want to do this to detect hand gestures (sign language alphabet). Can someone please help me.

The code below is available on the opencv documentation. I want to know how to use this for my the purpose stated above.

```
// Data for visual representation
int width = 512, height = 512;
Mat image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);

// Set up training data
float labels[4] = { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0 };
Mat labelsMat(4, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);

// Storing as Mat objects of floats
float trainingData[4][2] = { { 501, 10 }, { 255, 10 }, { 501, 255 }, { 10, 501 } };
Mat trainingDataMat(4, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);

// Set up SVM's parameters
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

// Train the SVM
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);

Vec3b green(0, 255, 0), blue(255, 0, 0);
// Show the decision regions given by the SVM
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
    {
        Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1, 2) << j, i);
        float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);

        if (response == 1)
            image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = green;
        else if (response == -1)
            image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = blue;
    }

// Show the training data
int thickness = -1;
int lineType = 8;
circle(image, Point(501, 10), 5, Scalar(0, 0, 0), thickness, lineType);
circle(image, Point(255, 10), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
circle(image, Point(501, 255), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
circle(image, Point(10, 501), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);

// Show support vectors
thickness = 2;
lineType = 8;
int c = SVM.get_support_vector_count();

for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
{
    const float* v = SVM.get_support_vector(i);
    circle(image, Point((int)v[0], (int)v[1]), 6, Scalar(128, 128, 128), thickness, lineType);
}

imwrite("result.png", image);        // save the image

imshow("SVM Simple Example", image); // show it to the user
waitKey(0);
```

}

Comment: Please show a minimal effort about the process. Where did you stuck? How SVM works ? Finding the defects ? Labeling them ? Bad results on a distinct hand dataset ? Parameter sensitivity ? openCV / c++ ? Basically you need train for every letter (segment out the hand from the image, find its defects, save the defects to an array and label the array with a letter), then use the final SVM.

Comment: Hi, I apologize for being so vague but I do not understand SVM very well and it is my first time exploring machine learning so I was not sure how to phrase the question. However you did answer my question, as I wanted to know how to use the defects that I have obtained, with the SVM classifier. Thank you very much.


Just to recap, Will I will be using the letters as labels and the defect array as the corresponding training data?

Comment: Yes, there you go. Find defect points, create training data, construct also the label array, train SVM. Then use it for completely another defects array and check out if it is suitably trained.